# Why is my circle uneven when i rotate it

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing, gif

Ok, so I'm kinda new to Photoshop (I have CC )so this is probably stupid question, but when I create a circle (I always make it even; the one i have now has W:680px and H is the same size) and use PS shapes and put them around the circle, and then rotate the circle with the shapes, it gets kinda uneven at the end after 360°, but it's still ok. But the moment i use my own things around the edge and try to rotate the circle, it gets horribly off the path only after 90°. I made quick examples (ignore how horrible it looks haha). So, I used exactly the same circle as i used with the custom shapes (rotating was ok with it then), only I put different things that i found somewhere else, around the edge. So here goes the first frame:

[image]

...and this is what happens after I rotate it only 90°:

[image]

and it is even worse after 180° :( I don't know what to do. Why is rotating with custom shapes ok, but when I use the same circle, only with shapes from the net or self made, it get so horribly of the path? I'm sorry this is so long but it's bugging me. And also sorry for my English.

Comment: Korean haircuts? ;)

Comment: Lol,yeah :D SHINee haha

Answer (score 5):

[image: rotation]

The center of your second circle example is not centered, as seen in the overlay of both images attached - possibly when rotating the grouped items (heads) the original center (pos1) you think is the yellow point. I think you can adjust the rotation point so that the yellow remains centered